# Is AppFabric 1.1 compatible with Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016, sharepoint, appfabric

So I am trying to install Sharepoint Server 2019 on a box with Windows Server 2016 that is not connected to the Internet.

You can see the software and hardware requirements here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-2019

Ok, so it requires Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server.

But apparently Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 can't be installed on Windows Server 2016:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115 (Look at supported operating systems)

Wha...?

I downloaded WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe from that link, and the installer wouldn't run.  Is there some other link that I should download it from?

Comment: `The Microsoft SharePoint Products Preparation Tool installs the following prerequisites on SharePoint servers in a farm` - Have you tried installing Sharepoint?

Comment: Yes.  I can't use the Preparation Tool since it requires internet access.